# Flutter Creating multiple layouts

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, flutter

I am new to Flutter and I would like to know how you can create fragments 
in the middle of an app like in this image right here.

Also I've been wondering if you can align the 'In Progress ' with 2 datetimeWidgets in a row

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn1Ct.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    // your child widgets here
    // In Progress widget + 2 date time Widget
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        ProgressWidget(),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DateTimeWidget1(),
            DateTimeWidget2(),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: thank you :) 
but i ve been looking for a way to create the two fragments below
the 'Documents ' and the 'Assign ' 
that s the part that i ve been stuck on :/

Comment: you can wrap them in Expanded widget!